# Adding a date filter search to a current autofilter VBA line

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I was helped out immensely by a bobajob on another question regarding autofilters.   However, I need to complicate things slightly.  The following code allows a user to search a small data sheet of products in excel and have it auto filter.  It works splendidly (thanks again bobajob!!), but I need to complicate it slightly by adding a date search function.  This file relates to some products and the dates refer to production dates, expiration dates, etc.  The original search function allowed for a certain brand to be searched, where it was produced, and the serial code number...but now I have to add the ability to pull up when these items were manufactured between two dates, but still retaining the search criteria of where they were manufactured, etc.

Is the best way to do this by modifying this code below?  Or adding in a separate module?  That can still link the two fields, etc?

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A9:J1018").AutoFilter
        For i = 1 To 10
            If .Cells(3, i) <> vbNullString Then
                .Range("A9:J1018").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=.Cells(3, i)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I'm familiar with the original, I'll have a go at this one too. The following will test row three (the first criteria) to see if it is a date, and if so will use row 3 and row 4 to define the range of dates to filter on:

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A9:J1018").AutoFilter
        For i = 1 To 10
            If .Cells(3, i) <> vbNullString Then
                If IsDate(.Cells(3, i)) Then
                    .Range("A9:J1018").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(.Cells(3, i)), Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(.Cells(4, i))
                Else
                    .Range("A9:J1018").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=.Cells(3, i)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Note I converted the dates to longs first, which should hopefully get rid of any ambiguity in date localisation.

Comment: Yup!  That worked.  I modified the worksheet change feature to include the field below it and it works like a charm!  Quite resourceful sir!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answers have solved your problems, would you mind accepting them?

Comment: Accepted sir! Thanks again!!